# Do simple functions play a role in differentiation?

Tags: real-analysis

Integrability of functions over measure spaces is often defined by means of simple functions.

This makes me wonder whether or not the simple functions should play a role in studying derivative of (smooth) functions. However the first obstacle is perhaps properly defining the derivative of simple functions. So here are my two questions:

1. How can we define the derivative of simple functions? (Maybe as distributions?) Reference(s), or example(s) can be very helpful.
2. If the previous part has a "nice" answer, then I would ask whether there is a relation between the derivative of a smooth (bounded) function $f$ and the sequence of the derivatives of simple functions $s_n$ that (uniformly) converge to it.

Any comments/answers are appreciated and are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Below is example 7.5 of baby Rudin

> Let $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$, and $f(x) = 0$. We have that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly. But $f'_n(x) \not\to f'(x)$.

That is to say: uniform convergence of a sequence of functions says nothing about the convergence of their derivatives.

---

Next, you are doing your "intuition" wrong. If you take seriously the notion, introduced by the fundamental theorem of calculus, that differentiation is the "reverse" of integration, your conclusion should be whether simple functions should appear naturally as **the derivative** in some sort of approximation to derivative of functions.

With the integrals of simple functions being continuous piecewise linear functions, your question then should have been:

> Do continuous piecewise linear functions play a role in studying the derivative of (smooth) functions?

And indeed, the answer is yes. You have just discovered the beginning of modern numerical analysis in the form of [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

---

Regarding the comment: let me be a bit more precise than my previous attempt at a comment. The point is this:

1. We know classically that simple functions are not differentiable. So in order to define their derivatives, we have to "add new 'functions'". One way to do this is as you noted distribution theory.
2. However, in order to "approximate" the derivatives by said *generalized derivatives* of simple functions, you need to also define a means to evaluate "approximation". This is obtained by giving a topology on your extended space of functions.
3. And indeed if you consider the distributions (continuous linear functionals on the space of compactedly supported smooth functions), you can actually choose a topology (the weak-star one) such that whenever $\phi_k$ is a sequence of distributions converging in the weak-star topology to $\phi$, you also have $D\phi_k \to D\phi$ in the same topology. So you can indeed say that distribution theory gives a possibility of "approximating" the derivative by starting from step functions.
4. The problem is that this construction is not very meaningful. Given any set you can *always* equip it with a topology where basically any convergence that you want is true. But that may not be the "natural" one. And if you want to ask questions like your question 2, generally you want to place restrictions on what kinds of additional objects you want to add to your theory, and what kinds of topologies you allow. And this runs right against what you have done in the previous steps.
5. For example, as you have seen already in Rudin's example, which I remark operates in the realm of *smooth functions* that there can be some problems. Since we have that the smooth functions are distributions, we see that the topology that I described in step 3 will also make Rudin's example converge. From this alone we see that there is no hope of reconciling this weak topology with the topology of pointwise convergence on smooth functions.

Comment: Of course I had the example from Rudin in mind when I asked this question, but that is not really applicable here since my simple functions are not differentiable in the ordinary sense of word. I wanted to know if using a more sophisticated definition of differentiation (maybe by distributions) can give some positive results in that direction.